# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error when calling external web service in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I tried to call GetCityWeatherByZIP from Weather.asmx web service and get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** error.
Can anyone advise on this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   dataType: 'jsonp',  
                   url: "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP",
                   data:{ZIP: 10007},
                   success : function(jsonp) {
                       alert (jsonp);
                   }
               });
           });
            function processSuccess(response) { alert('success');
            }

            function processError(data) {
            alert('err'+data);
                //alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
            } 

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input id="btnCallWebService" value="Call web service" type="button" />
        <div id="response" ></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Other than JSONP other data types gives error as XMLHTTPRequest failed to load. But web service returns XML. What is the solution?

Comment: How to change request to expect XML or change the web service to respond with JSONP?

Comment: "Other than JSONP other data types gives error as XMLHTTPRequest failed to load" — What error? What does Google say if you search for that error?

Comment: "How to change request to expect XML" — change the bit where your code says "jsonp" to "xml"

Comment: "How to … change the web service to respond with JSONP?" — edit the code hosted on `wsf.cdyne.com`. The specifics are too details to go into here, especially without access to the current code. If it is well engineered, then it will probably be just replacing a "Turn arbitrary data structure to XML" function call with a "Turn arbitrary data structure to JSON" function call and wrapping it with a callback routine as well as changing the content-type.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling jQuery to process the response as JSONP, but the web service is returning XML.

JSONP works by loading a JavaScript program (with embedded data), and the error you get is because XML starts with `<` which isn't a character that can start a JavaScript program.

Either change your request to expect XML or change the web service to respond with JSONP.

Answer (score -1):

The webservice returns an XML response and you try to parse it as an JSONP